# How to implement Cascading in NHibernate using ClassMap (mapping by code)?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, cascade, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

I am having some trouble with what seems to be a relatively simple cascading operation, but which I simply cannot get to work.
I have four (simplified) classes:

```
class Class
{
    uint?  ID; //IDs are null when they are created, the database automatically generates IDs. IDs are never null when retrieved from Database.
    Classroom Classroom;
    List<ClassStudent> Students;
}
class Student
{
    uint? ID; //IDs are null when they are created, the database automatically generates IDs. IDs are never null when retrieved from Database.
    string Name;
    Classroom Homeroom;
}
class Classroom
{
    uint? ID; //IDs are null when they are created, the database automatically generates IDs. IDs are never null when retrieved from Database.
    string FloorNumber;
    string RoomNumber;
}
class ClassStudent
{
    Class Class;
    uint SeatNumber;
    Student Student;
}
```

When I save a `Class`, I want to be able to just type in personal and address information without worrying about whether these `Student`s and `Classroom`s already exist in the database, and I want the Cascade logic to automatically persist new `Classroom`s and `Student`s, and reference existing ones based not on their `ID`s, but on their information.
For example, saving a `Classroom` with `FloorNumber: "69", RoomNumber: 420` while an identical `Classroom` exists in the database should result in a reference to the `Classroom.ID` instead of persisting a new `Classroom`. `Student` works the exact same way.

(Oh, and, of course this is a silly way to handle School information; the classes are stand-ins. I just find it easier to work with tangible examples rather than `foo`s and `bar`s)

However, I cannot get the Cascade to work properly.

The first thing I have tried is of course just to have my `ClassMap`s' references `Cascade.SaveUpdate()`, for example:

```
class ClassesMap: ClassMap<Class>
{
    public ClassesMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.ID)
            .GeneratedBy.Native();
        References(x => x.Classroom)
            .Cascade.SaveUpdate();
        HasMany(x => x.ClassStudent)
            .KeyColumn("ClassID")
            .Cascade.All();
            
    }
}
class ClassStudentMap: ClassMap<ClassStudent>
{
    public ClassStudentMap()
    {
        CompositeId()
            .KeyReference(x => x.Class, "ClassID")
            .KeyProperty(x => x.SeatNumber)
        References(x => x.Student)
            .Cascade.SaveUpdate();
    }
}
class StudentMap: ClassMap<Student>
{
    public StudentMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.ID);
            .GeneratedBy.Native();
        Map(x => x.Name);
        References(x => x.Homeroom)
            .Cascade.SaveUpdate();
    }
}
class ClassroomMap: ClassMap<Classroom>
{
    public ClassroomMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.ID);
            .GeneratedBy.Native();
        Map(x => x.FloorNumber);
        Map(x => x.RoomNumber);
    }
}
```

The result of this is that there is no prevention of duplicate `Classroom`s and `Student`s; inserting a new `Class` will also insert its `Classroom` and `Student`s, regardless of whether identical `Classroom`s and `Student`s already exist in the database.

So, I tried to declare the `Student`s' and `Classroom`s' information as `Unique`

```
class StudentMap: ClassMap<Student>
{
    public StudentMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.ID);
            .GeneratedBy.Native();
        Map(x => x.Name).UniqueKey("UniqueStudent");
        References(x => x.Homeroom)
            .Cascade.SaveUpdate()
            .UniqueKey("UniqueStudent");
    }
}
class ClassroomMap: ClassMap<Classroom>
{
    public ClassroomMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.ID);
            .GeneratedBy.Native();
        Map(x => x.FloorNumber)
            .UniqueKey("UniqueClassroom");
        Map(x => x.RoomNumber)
            .UniqueKey("UniqueClassroom");
    }
}
```

However, this resulted in `Class`es being unable to save to the database, because it could not save its `Student`s and `Classroom` because they conflict with existing `Unique` entries.

Third thing I tried was a custom Cascade Logic. I replaced the `Cascade.SaveUpdate()`s with `Cascade.None()`, and rewrote my code so I would `GetOrCreate` each `Classroom`, and then `GetOrCreate` each `Student`, and only then save the `Class`
Example of `GetOrCreate` as applies to `Classroom` (`Student` has one just like it):

```
Classroom GetOrCreate(Classroom newClassroom)
{
    Classroom? extant = GetFromDatabase(newClassroom);
    if(extant != null)
        return extant;
    SaveToDatabase(newClassroom);
    return GetFromDatabase(newClassroom);
}
```

But to no avail; now when I save a `Class` it complains that it references a transient `Classroom` (and if I skip the `Classroom`, `ClassStudent` references a transient `Student`), and that I must persist it to the Database - despite the fact that the transient `Classroom` it references was retrieved from the Database, and I therefor know it is persistent.

I need help figuring out what to do, please.

Answer (score 0):

remove `.Cascade.SaveUpdate()` and use `session.Merge` if newClassroom can be some detached but persisted entity. Example:

```
ISession session = ;
using (var tx = sess.BeginTransaction())
{
    Classroom someDeserializedClassroom = ;
    Student student = ;
    
    // merge will update the existing class if present otherwise insert a new one
    student.AddToClass(session.Merge(someDeserializedClassroom), seatNumber);
    
    tx.Commit();
}
```

however if you have the id of the classroom only then

```
ISession session = ;
using (var tx = sess.BeginTransaction())
{
    var classroomId = ;
    Student student = ;
    
    // Load will create a lazyloading proxy which is only used to satisfy the room here
    student.AddToClass(session.Load(classroomId), seatNumber);
    
    tx.Commit();
}
```